How can i use the attachment field in wp-media to filter my images using acf wp-json?
Please can you help me.
How can i use the attachment field in wp-media to filter my images using acf wp-json?

Basically i would like to pass tournament_id in a ACF WP-JSON url.
for example like the below:
/wp-json/wp/v2/media&tournament_id=ISBM
Any help would be great.
Thanks,
Matt
